# Flex get extremely slow response some php script

Tags: php, flash, apache-flex, apache, request

I am fixing up a php script to recieve a byte64 encoded image and store it to database

Here is my problem the script takes very long time, sometimes up to 5 minutes, to respond when flash calls the script(via a post request)

(i test it with a very small image)

if i remove the byte64 encoded data from the request it loads fast, and if i call the script from the browser with no data it is fast

i tried removing all php script from the script file so no php is run, and with data it is still slow.

My guess is that this is somehow server related, but i have no clue what this could be, other than it must happen before php is run.

and i have no htaccess file on the site,

Comment: Why are you storing a base64 image into a database?!

Comment: Post your code that sends the data to the server

Answer (score 0):

"if i remove the byte64 encoded data from the request it loads fast"

So you know exactly where you issue is at. Test the queries, if they're not optimizable, store your images the normal way.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up rewriting the script to a normal upload and then store them as files, storing images in DB is bad mojo, but was trying to avoid having to rewrite the intire script at the time :)

but thanks for your time!